# python plotting with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

So, I have values that look like this. Now, with pandas plotting function, like 
upperband.plot(), it shows broken line for the first few values like below:

```
2015-03-12           NaN
2015-03-13           NaN
2015-03-16           NaN
2015-03-17           NaN
2015-03-18           NaN
2015-03-19           NaN
2015-03-20           NaN
2015-03-23           NaN
2015-03-24           NaN
2015-03-25           NaN
2015-03-26           NaN
2015-03-27           NaN
2015-03-30           NaN
2015-03-31           NaN
2015-04-01           NaN
2015-04-02           NaN
2015-04-06           NaN
2015-04-07           NaN
2015-04-08           NaN
2015-04-09    567.812173
2015-04-10    567.456120
2015-04-13    567.607916
2015-04-14    567.968762
```

[image]

How can I ignore these NaN values? I want to start with a smooth line and ignore the broken line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091012/find-a-null-value-and-drop-from-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235401/remove-nan-from-pandas-series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just ignore the data that is missing you can use

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: your first answer would be better as `df = df.dropna()` as shown in the two link I provided. Your second answer misses the mark as the OP clearly stated that NaNs should be ignored.